# Initialize redux store after load asynchronous data

Tags: react-native, redux, asyncstorage

I am using Redux to manage the state of my app and [AsyncStorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage) to persist some data of the store.

I'm using the following way to initialize the store data because I want to access the store without any initialization function but directly from store variable. I know that store's data is read-only but it works fine for me.

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import store from './store';

export default App = () => {
  const [ready, setReady] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
     AsyncStorage.getItem('reduxData').then((data) => {

       store.getState().ReducerA.sampleItem1 = data.sampleItem1;
       store.getState().ReducerB.sampleItem2 = data.sampleItem2;
       store.getState().ReducerC.sampleItem3 = data.sampleItem3;

       setReady(true);
     });
  }, [setReady]);

  if (!ready) return null;
  
  return (
     <Provider store={store}>
        ...
    </Provider>
  )

}'
```

What is the best way to initialize store correctly? ( Without external library such us [Redux Persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist) and without wrapping the store in a function )

Comment: Why are you not using redux-persist? What is the use case here?

Comment: I'm using the code-splitting strategy of redux and redux-persist does not support code-splitting yet as I know